# Neo4j cypher time interval histogram query of time tree

Tags: neo4j, timestamp, time-series, cypher

I would like to build an histogram on time series stored as time tree in neo4j.
The data structures are event done by a user each has timestamp, say user purchases category. 
What I need to have is the number of browsing on each category by each user between start and end time, with interval of (1 second to days)
My model feats graph db very nicely, as I read [neo4j documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/cypher-cookbook-path-tree.html) I could not find any way to do it in one query, and I'm afraid that calling for each user would be very slow.

[image: Time tree model]

I am aware to cypher capabilities, but I have no idea how to create such query.
I am looking for something like this (not working)

```
MATCH startPath=(root)-[:`2010`]->()-[:`12`]->()-[:`31`]->(startLeaf),
endPath=(root)-[:`2011`]->()-[:`01`]->()-[:`03`]->(endLeaf),
valuePath=(startLeaf)-[:NEXT*0..]->(middle)-[:NEXT*0..]->(endLeaf),
vals=(middle)-[:VALUE]->(event)
WHERE root.name = 'Root'
RETURN event.name, count(*)
ORDER BY event.name ASC
GROUP BY event.timestamp % 1000*60*10 // 10 minutes histogram bar
```

Then I'd like to have a report, for how many users browse to each site category:

0-9 news 5, commerce 3 ; 10-19 news 6, commerce 19; 1 20-29 news 2, commerce 8;

Any idea if it is optional with neo4j time tree model?
if so how? :-)

Comment: There's no "GROUP BY" in cypher; you should calculate that extra column in a `WITH` expression, and then if you return distinct on that, it'll operate the same way.

Comment: Yes I know GROUP BY is missing, I would like to create time based histogram. can I do something like this:
"WITH event.timestamp % 1000*60*10"  getting 10 minutes bars?

Comment: If you put the `event.timestamp % 1000*60*10` in your `RETURN` statement it should automatically group since you're using the `count` function to aggregate.  So maybe something like `RETURN event.name, event.timestamp % 1000*60*10 AS slice, count(*) ORDER BY slice`?

Comment: GROUP BY is not missing, it is automatically inferred from the aggregating and non-aggregating columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
MATCH
  startPath=(root)-[:`2010`]->()-[:`12`]->()-[:`31`]->(startLeaf),
  endPath=(root)-[:`2011`]->()-[:`01`]->()-[:`03`]->(endLeaf),
  valuePath=(startLeaf)-[:NEXT*0..]->(middle)-[:NEXT*0..]->(endLeaf),
  vals=(middle)-[:VALUE]->(event)
WHERE root.name = 'Root'
RETURN event.name, event.timestamp % 1000*60*10 AS slice, count(*)
ORDER BY slice ASC
```

Basically I just added the `event.timestamp % 1000*60*10` into the return so that Neo4j will use that as a grouping criteria

Comment: I thing the count(*) is not right, I am building a test and I'll report soon :-)

Comment: Great, let me know! ;)